# How-To add Custom field in Wordpress wp-ecommerce Categories?

Tags: customization, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I'm using [WP e-Commerce (Wordpress Plugin)](http://www.instinct.co.nz/e-commerce/). I want to add a field in Categories (image field for category background). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify that a bit? It already allows for uploading of an image to be used as the category image. Are you looking to attach another image to the category for some other reason?

Comment: Yes there is a category image already in wp-ecommerce categories, but my requirement is to add another image, that will be used as category logo.

Comment: gotcha. i'm thinking that would require a ton of backend work with uploading images, adding to the db, and calling the image.

Comment: A workaround might be to use jQuery to find those categories by class in the page and add css classes to each one that can then be used to call a background image via CSS.

Comment: isn't there a way to use meta field?

Comment: if there is, i'm not sure how to do it. you should try posting on the wp-ecommerce forum. might get better results.

http://getshopped.org/forums/